# SQL Update query of a string field

Tags: sql

I have a field "Group" with many different string values. I want to change all the rows where this field is "Pharmacy" and set the same field to "Pharm". I wrote this query

```
UPDATE Course
SET Course.Group = "Pharm"
WHERE Course.Group = "Pharmacy"
```

When I run this query, it executes but nothing change in my db. Is there something wrong?

Comment: String need to be put between single quotes in SQL: `'Pharm'` or `'Pharmacy'` double quotes are for identifiers

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
UPDATE Course
SET Course.[Group] = 'Pharm'
WHERE Course.[Group] = 'Pharmacy'
```

Double quotes are object Identifiers in SQL Server, and Single Quotes are the String identifiers.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code, the original code was with single quotes but due to the fact it wasn't working I tried also double-quotes